# Program to find prime numbers in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, primes

I wrote some code to display the prime numbers between 2 and a user-chosen number, following the pseudocode on wikipedia. I am not sure why this does not work, as I have the increments correct following Erastothenes' Sieve. Please help me.

I have tried changing the bounds but this did not work.

There are no errors, but it returns the wrong output. If I enter 10, it returns 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.

```
n=input("Enter an upper limit: ");
nums= 2:n;
p=2;
for i = p:sqrt(n)
    for j = (i^2):i:sqrt(n)
        nums(j) = 0;
    end
end
for k = 1:n-1
    if nums(k) ~= 0
        disp(nums(k))
    end
end
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be more clear on "not working", are the results wrong, does it result in errors, does it make your computer explode...?

Comment: The `j` loop need to go until `n` not `sqrt(n)` otherwise how this code could check if a number > sqrt(n) can be divided by an already found prime number ? Also nums start at 2 not 1, so you should write `nums(j-1) = 0;`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `primes` function in MATLAB for this

```
N = 10;        % upper limit
p = primes(N); % List of all primes up to (and including) N
```

With one step less automation, you could use another in-built `isprime`

```
p = 1:N;                  % List of all numbers up to N
p( ~isprime( p ) ) = [];  % Remove non-primes
```

Finally without using built-ins, we can address your code!
I assume you're referring to [this pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Pseudocode) for the Sieve of Eratosthenes on Wikipedia.

```
 Input: an integer n > 1.

 Let A be an array of Boolean values, indexed by integers 2 to n,
 initially all set to true.

 for i = 2, 3, 4, ..., not exceeding √n:
   if A[i] is true:
     for j = i2, i2+i, i2+2i, i2+3i, ..., not exceeding n:
       A[j] := false.

 Output: all i such that A[i] is true.
```

I'll follow it step by step, pointing out differences to your code:

```
n = 10;
A = [false; true(n-1,1)];   % array of true Booleans, first element (1) is not prime
% But I've included a first element to make indexing easier.
% In your code, you were using index 'i' which was incorrect, as your array started at 2.
% Two options: (1) take my approach and pad the array
%              (2) take your approach and using indices i-1 and j-1
for ii = 2:sqrt(n)
    if A(ii) == true        % YOU WERE MISSING THIS STEP!
        for jj = ii^2:ii:n   % YOU ONLY LOOPED UNTIL SQRT(n)!
            A(jj) = false;
        end
    end
end

p = find(A);
disp(p)
```

This outputs the expected values.

Note that, at the end of the manual looping method, `A` is equivalent to `isprime(1:n)`, mirroring my earlier suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

There is two mistakes in your code:

1. The multiple should be check until `n` and not `sqrt(n)`
2. Since your `nums` vector start with 2 and not 1, if you want to
   access the right value you need to use `nums(j-1) = 0`

So:

```
n=100
nums= 2:n;
p=2;
for i = p:sqrt(n)
    for j = (i^2):i:n
        nums(j-1) = 0;
    end
end
for k = 1:n-1
    if nums(k) ~= 0
        disp(nums(k))
    end
end
```

Noticed that you can skip one for loop using a modulo, it's probably not faster than the previous solution since this code create a logical index that include each prime that already been found.

```
n   = 100
nums= 2:n;

for i = 2:sqrt(n) 
    nums(mod(nums,i)==0 & nums != i) = [];
end

nums.'
```

I simply delete the value in `nums` that can be divided by `x` but not `x`.

Comment: "Optimise" is used confidently here, I'm not sure invoking `mod` is actually going to be quicker than directly indexing the array elements...

Answer (score -2):

```
n=input('Enter a number:')
F=factor(n);
if F==n
    disp('Prime number.')
else
    disp('Not a prime number.')
end
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.